# Passar por parametro o valor do input do html com php

Tags: php, html

Boa noite
Como faço para passar parametro do input html e mandar por parametro para receber em php. Na hora de submeter se o campo está vazio então ele tem que chamar a função identifica qual campo. Segue o código abaixo:
inserir a descrição da imagem aqui[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Php, antes da inserção estou fazendo assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
é que inclusao=2 significa que tem campo para preencher, Então lá no html é veriicado isso, retornado via get.

Comment: Olá! Utilize seu código no conteúdo de sua questão. Não coloque imagem de código, mas sim o código puro. Recomendo a leitura: Como fazer uma boa pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
Saudações.

Comment: Envia e valide usando javascript.

Answer (score 1):

O correto seria você colocar esses inputs dentro de um formulário definindo um "name" para cada campo e um action para o formulário, você irá utilizar o $_Post para capturar os valores. Lembrando que você captura o valor de acordo com o "name" que você determinou no input.
Segue os exemplos:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/tutorial.forms.php

Depois que você capturar as informações, você pode fazer as verificações como achar melhor.
Por exemplo, se um campo vir nulo, você pode colocar uma condição e retornar um echo contendo o erro para o usuário.

Você também poderia utilizar HTML5 para tratar esse problema, se você colocar a tag "required" dentro do input, caso o usuário não preenche-lo, uma mensagem será exibida.

Espero ter te ajudado, caso ainda houver dúvidas, estou disposto a te ajudar!